# How to check if bool already exists

Tags: c, boolean

I an developing a lib for use on an embedded platform. I have code in a header that is part of the lib with 
`typdef enum bool {false, true} bool;`

If the lib user has already defined a type named bool, how can I code this so that my lib does not attempt to re-declare it?

Currently I have used #defines

```
#ifndef _BOOL 
#define _BOOL 
typedef enum bool{...
#endif
```

however this depends on a user that has bool defined also defining _BOOL

Is there a way of checking if types`with specific names already exist?

(Note this is a C Question, not C++, and neither I nor my assumed lib user is using stdbool, Ta)

Comment: If the platform is embedded, you should already know if `bool` exists, shouldn't you?

Comment: Not if I create the lib and it is called by another author's application (on same platform) that may define bool itself??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Your library probably should just define its own, distinct boolean type:

```
typedef enum { libname_false, libname_true } libname_bool;
```

Within your library implementation you could alias those to more convenient names as you desire.

Incidentally, you should not name preprocessor macros with leading underscores; [those names are reserved for the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 1):

I would go a way you going now, supplying some kind of your_lib_config.h with #defines like HAS_BOOL_DEFINED or anything similar which affects your library configuration. So user will be responsible to adjust settings in config header before using your library.